# The rope data structure, redundancy on wikipedia or am I missing something?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, redundancy, recursive-datastructures

Why are there [duplicate nodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSearch_rope.jpg) like `9`, `1` and `6` in the wikipedia article on [rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29)?

Am I missing something, or those nodes are fully redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they (the non-leaf nodes with single children) seem completely pointless.  there doesn't seem to be anything in the [linked to paper from boehm et al](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.9450&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that is equivalent (there they use "normal" balanced trees).

they make no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

From the article:

`Each node has a "weight" equal to the length of its string plus the sum of all the weights in its left subtree.`

Those numbers appear to represent a weight of the node, based on the size of its children. So two nodes with value `6` do not have to have the same values. There is a `Hello_` of weight 6 and a `_Simon` of weight 6.

**Edit**

For non-leaf values, the duplicates appear to be there to make the leaves at the same depth.

Comment: that's not what the question is talking about, i think.  look at the non-leaf nodes with single children.

Answer (score 1):

Those nodes could come about after a delete. Eventually you would want to rebalance so every node has two children (or a leaf) and the depth of each branch would be the same.